# videoMaximumDuration doesn't limit the duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like the user to pick a video from his libary and limit it to 45 seconds (Like WhatsApp - you can edit the video and the video which will be sent is not longer than 45 seconds.

But if I use the following code, it does pick a video regardless of the duration, and I cant trim it (Tested it with a video, length 1 minute)

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self; 
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 45.0f; //?
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

        [[self parentViewController] presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
        [imagePickerController release];
```

In WhatsApp, I get the following screen, which I want to reproduce:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

make sure you set allowsEditing to YES before presenting the controller.

imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set allowsEditing to true before after setting the video duration

make it in that order

```
 imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 45.0
 imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
```

Comment: Which is it? Before or after? You wrote *"set allowsEditing to true before after setting"*. Pick one - either before or after. Not both. And how is this an improvement over the other, 11-year old answer?